# how to search and replace specific src="url" tag in html using perl?

Tags: html, regex, perl

Let's say I have a variable with a bunch of text in it, including URLs that are within normal HTML tags.  In particular, I'm interested in the src= element of a tag.  Let's say I know of the exact src= string that I want to search for in that bunch of text and I want to replace that with some other text . . . here's some of what I've tried (pseudo code):

```perl
my $bunchotxt = << 'END_MESSAGE';
<a href="http://link.com/image.gif"><img class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-295" src="http://link.com/image.gif" alt="shredding" width="150" height="150" /></a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis convallis fringilla dui eget cursus. Nullam in mauris viverra elit pharetra fringilla. Pellentesque gravida ligula sit amet magna blandit, semper luctus enim semper. Nam a sem ut ex aliquam consectetur. Nulla enim metus, porta at elementum non, facilisis ullamcorper nisl. Vestibulum sed iaculis ante. Nullam mollis luctus posuere.

Suspendisse ipsum odio, iaculis in malesuada id, varius
END_MESSAGE

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(
    string => $bunchotxt
);

while ( my $tag = $parser->get_tag('img') ) {
    #print $tag->as_is, "\n";
    for my $attr ( qw( src ) ) {
        $replaceStr = sprintf qq{%s="%s"\n}, $attr, $tag->get_attr($attr);
        $parsedtag =~ s/"//g;
        my @bits = $url->path_segments( );
        $cidreplace{$unparsedtag} = $path;
    }
    my $replaceStr = "src:\"replaced\"";
    $bunchotxt =~ s/$findURL/$replaceStr/g;
    print "$buchotxt\n";
}
```

Comment: Then you just need to match the string you want to match. You ignored the `"` characters in the original source.

Comment: Your first double quote in the search pattern is in the wrong place. Also, you don't need to escape `=` or `:`, but you _do_ need to escape `.` in this case since you want to match a literal dot.

Comment: Man, I wish I could re-post this question the way it really SHOULD have been asked.In the code I'm trying to get work, the $findstr character is populated with another loop that uses HTML::Tokeparser::Simple to get a list of all the src= elements from the orig text.  So $findstr ends up having the value of what's returned from the Tokeparser portion of the code.  I've tried escaping that with quotemeta() but that doesn't seem to make any difference. Hoping you would be willing to weigh in again knowing that.

Comment: Okay, I revamped the above code taking into account the comment I just made above.  Hopefully someone would be willing to take another stab at this one.

Comment: Your example still has a bunch of extraneous crap in it that doesn't actually showcase the problem! For instance, where does `$findURL` come from? That's kind of important, since it's the crux of the issue. Also, you said you tried to use `quotemeta`, but I don't see it anywhere in your code. Please learn about how to create a [mcve].

Comment: You don't appear to have asked a question. I can only guess that it's another *this doesn't work, please fix it* post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we need to distill your problem down to the part we actually care about. Your example code is not great because it contains a lot of unrelated errors, so I've taken some liberties in stripping out stuff I didn't feel was absolutely necessary to solve the problem. I also added some line breaks to your HTML to help with the horizontal scrolling.

That leaves us with this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

my $bunchotxt = << 'END_MESSAGE';
<a href="http://link.com/image.gif">
  <img
      class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-295"
      src="http://link.com/image.gif"
      alt="shredding"
      width="150"
      height="150" />
</a>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis convallis
fringilla dui eget cursus. Nullam in mauris viverra elit pharetra fringilla.
Pellentesque gravida ligula sit amet magna blandit, semper luctus enim semper.
Nam a sem ut ex aliquam consectetur. Nulla enim metus, porta at elementum non,
facilisis ullamcorper nisl. Vestibulum sed iaculis ante. Nullam mollis luctus
posuere.

Suspendisse ipsum odio, iaculis in malesuada id, varius
END_MESSAGE

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(string => $bunchotxt);

while (my $tag = $parser->get_tag('img')) {
    my $src = $tag->get_attr('src');
    $bunchotxt =~ s/\Qsrc="$src"\E/src:"replaced"/g;
    print "$bunchotxt\n";
}
```

And the first line of the result is:

```
<a href="http://link.com/image.gif"><img class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-295" src:"replaced" ...
```

Comment: This is a great solution.  After a little more research, I found set_attr for tokeparser.  That actually works too, but I wasn't able to see how to commit that change back into the string.  This works 100%.  Thank you for being patient with my admittedly hurried sample code as well.

Comment: @2crd3o So is the `src:` in the replacement a typo that should have been `src=`?